# Bluetooth or Ibeacon Scanning on Ios Safari with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, bluetooth, mobile-safari

Is there any way to scan ibeacons or other bluetooth 4.0 devices with javascript on ios devices?

I can get data on Chrome Desktop edition with chrome.bluetooth but i couldnt find a way to scan ble devices on browser.

I dont want to use phonegap or other frameworks. Also is there a list that ios safari supported hardware outputs? I can get accelerometer, gyro and compass but i couldnt get other datas.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also interested in something like that, did you find something ?

Comment: not yet, but i am searching about physical web solutions